# RxJS Observable never completes (Angular)

Tags: angular, observable

I have my stream defined like this

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  things$: Observable<Thing[]>;

  constructor(private fooService: FooService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.things$ = this.fooService.getFoos() // Observable<Foo[]>
                      .pipe(
                        mergeAll(),
                        map(foo => this.thingService.getThing(foo.thingId)), // Observable<Thing>
                        zipAll()
                      );

  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is

1. Split my `Foo[]` into sequence of single `Foo` with `mergeAll`
2. Get a single `Thing` for each `Foo` with `map`
3. Merge all my `Thing`s into a `Thing[]` using `zipAll`

Now here is my template

```html
<div *ngIf="(things$ | async) as things; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="things.length">
    <div *ngFor="let thing of things">
      {{ thing.someAttr }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>

<div #loading>LOADING</div>
```

As the title says, I am stuck on loading state and the async pipe never resolve. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: this not how mergeAll works. please double check the docs for that. mergeAll would work on multiple emits of your source, but you have one single emit, which provides an array as a result. that is something different.

Comment: You can insert a tap() at each stage to see what is returned, then either set a breakpoint at each tap, or else do a console log of what is returned to make sure the observable is being transformed at each stage.  That'll also make it obvious where it is getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The approach would probably a little different. Since the Observable itself contains an array, you would need to handle it within the map function. Wouldn't need the `mergeAll` and `zipAll` in that case.

```
this.things$ = this.fooService.getFoos() // Observable<Foo[]>
    .pipe(
        map(foos => {
            let temp = [];
            foos.forEach(function(foo) {
                temp.push(this.thingService.getThing(foo.thingId));
            });
            return temp;
        });
```

Comment: This gives me an array of `Observable` while I want an array of `Thing`. I could use `async` pipe on each result on the template but that's not the original question. I want to know why it doesn't complete.